# EF6 Effort: seeding data leads to wrong ID's

Tags: entity-framework-6, effort

I'm using Effort 2.2.13.0 in my unit test project (xUnit). In a fixture, I'm adding company data to the Company table in the in-memory database.

```
CompanyId = 1, Name = "Company 1"
CompanyId = 2, Name = "Company 2"
CompanyId = 3, Name = "Company 3"
```

The strange behaviour is that after calling SaveChanges to store the data to the database, Company 2 has id 3 and Company 3 has id 2.

The fixture:

```cs
public class SharedDatabaseFixture
    {
        public SharedDatabaseFixture()
        {
            var connection = DbConnectionFactory.CreateTransient();
            Context = new TestDbContext(connection);

            Seed();
        }

        public TestDbContext Context { get; }

        private void Seed()
        {
            var addresses = AddressSeed.Get();
            var countries = CountrySeed.Get();
            var stores = StoreSeed.Get();
            var companies = CompanySeed.Get();
            var products = ProductSeed.Get();

            Context.Countries.AddRange(countries);
            Context.Companies.AddRange(companies);
            <!-- companies list is still correct -->
            Context.SaveChanges();
            <!-- Company 2 has id 3, company 3 has id 2 -->
        }
    }
```

I'm presetting the id's in the companies list, I also tried leaving them empty, but the result is the same.
Anyone seen this odd behaviour before?